# Repeatedly representing the frame of the collectionView's cell causes memory growth?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, reloaddata, custom-keyboard

I am working on a custom keyboard app and have encountered a difficult problem. I have inquired about some documents, but unfortunately did not find the answer. I want to ask everyone to help me.

The problem is this, when I type in the keyboard, the input results will be displayed in the candidate column.I use the ***UICollectionView*** to create the candidate column.

```
- (void)createCandideteColection {
    if (!_collectionView) {
        CGFloat height = self.frame.size.height-pinyinHeight-lineHeight; 
        CGFloat y = pinyinHeight+lineHeight; 
        CGFloat showButtonH = height; 
        CGFloat candidateShowWidth = self.frame.size.width - showButtonH;

        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        flow.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal; 
        flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20; 
        flow.minimumLineSpacing = 20;

        _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, candidateShowWidth, height) collectionViewLayout:flow];
        _collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _collectionView.dataSource = self;
        _collectionView.delegate = self;
        _collectionView.bounces = NO;
        _collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        [_collectionView registerClass:[GZCandidateCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"candidateCell"];
        [self addSubview:_collectionView];
    }
}
```

Sets the frame of the cell, ***_data*** changes with the input (each time a text is entered, ***_data*** changes once, and ***[collectionView reloadData]*** is called once).The width of the cell changes with the number of characters entered.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *str = _data[indexPath.row];
    CGFloat height = self.frame.size.height-pinyinHeight-lineHeight; 
    CGFloat width = str.length * 20 + 10;
    return CGSizeMake(width, height);
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    GZCandidateCell *cell = (GZCandidateCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"candidateCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *str = _data[indexPath.row];
    [cell setTitleText:str];
    return cell;
}
```

Assign ***titleLabel*** value, ***titleLabel*** size will be recalculate when calling ***[cell setTitleText:str]***.

when ***[collectionView removeFromSuperview]*** is called, collectionView will be destroyed,but there is little memory that cannot be released.Every time the input is completed and the ***collectionView*** is removed, some memory will not be released and will become a larger number after it is accumulated.

The reason why I will eventually locate this problem on the collectionView is because I don't create this collectionView, the memory does not grow.

Get input data and show on the ***collectionView***,and ***tabBar*** is the candidate column I mentioned above：

```
if (!_textKeyboard) {
    _textKeyboard = [[GZQwertyKeyboard alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, navigaitonHeight, SCREEN_WIDTH, height) andKeyboardType:type];
    _textKeyboard.backgroundColor = Color_background_kb;
    [self.view addSubview:_textKeyboard];
}
__weak KeyboardViewController *weakSelf = self;
__weak GZQwerty *getdata = [GZQwerty defaultQwerty]; //init qwerty

_textKeyboard.sendSelectedStr = ^(NSString *text) {
    if (!weakSelf.tabBar) {
        [weakSelf addCandidateBarView];
    }

    int asciiCode = [text characterAtIndex:0];
    [getdata sendInput:asciiCode complation:^(NSString *compontText, NSArray *candiateArray) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [weakSelf.tabBar changeShowText:candiateArray];
        });
    }];
};
```

Call ***[weakSelf addCandidateBarView]*** to create the ***tabBar***.Call ***[weakSelf.tabBar changeShowText:candiateArray]*** to modify the data source of the ***collectionView*** and refresh the ***collectionView***.Like this：

```
- (void)changeShowText:(NSArray*)textArr {
    _data = textArr;
    if (!_collectionView) {
        [self createCandideteColection];
    }
    [_collectionView reloadData];
    [_collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
}
```

When the keyboard is typed, if ***changeShowText:*** is not called, the memory is stable and there is no memory growth.

So, can anyone help me? Is there a better way than collectionView or how to avoid memory growth?Is it caused by repeated changes to the width of the cell?

Comment: Very confusing and unclear... please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @DonMag thank you，and ｉwill update late